# android studio emulator stopped my application

Tags: android

i was trying to make google map application but when i run it on android studio emulator the emulator stops it although when i run it on my phone it works [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWGAE.jpg)

..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

the code

```
package com.example.amr.googleplaces;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


    }
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION= Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15F;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getLocationPermission();
    }
    private void getDeviceLocation()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"getting the device location");
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        try
        {
            if(mLocationPermissionGranted)
            {
                Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG,"location found");
                            Location currentlocation = (Location)task.getResult();
                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentlocation.getLatitude(),currentlocation.getLongitude()),DEFAULT_ZOOM);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG,"current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this,"unable to find location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"security exception" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    private  void moveCamera(LatLng latLng,float zoom )
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"moving camera to latitude : "+ latLng.latitude +"longtitiude"+latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));



    }
    private void initMap()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFrafment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrafment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }
    private void getLocationPermission()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"get location permission");
        String[] permissions = {FINE_LOCATION,COARSE_LOCATION};
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),COARSE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();

            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult called");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 )
                {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i< grantResults.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG,"permission failed");
                           return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult :permission granted");

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    initMap();
                }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: We need a stacktrace.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please include the stacktrace.  You can do this by running `adb logcat` from the command line and looking for the exception that was thrown.

Comment: You haven't described what exactly is confusing to you about the error.

Comment: Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your emulator has

1. google apis intel x86 atom system image installed from sdk manager
2. Google API support
3. Graphics Hardware - GLES 2.0
4. OpenGL ES renderer --> SwiftShader

Also make sure your Google API Key is working correctly.

Also make sure you have this on `manifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: You followed all of the steps? try to clean cache, and create a new emulator with those specifications

Comment: @AmrHassan stilll having problems?